# Force lower case URLs, but exclude certain directories

Tags: .htaccess

I'm using the RewriteMap in my virtualhost to force all URLs to be lowercase.

However, I'd like to exclude certain directories and contents from being force to lowercase. Is this possible? This is my current htaccess, so I wondered if someone could show me what rule/condition i would need to add to exclude /static/ and /media/ directories from being forced to lowercase.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Don't redirect these
    #RewriteRule \.(gif|jpe?g|png|css|js)$ - [NC,L]

    # Always remove any trailing slashes
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.+)/$
    RewriteRule ^(.+)/$  /$1 [R=301,L]

    # Removes index.php
    RewriteCond $1 !\.(gif|jpe?g|png)$ [NC]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]

</IfModule>
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This is very much possible. Your above .htaccess code doesn't show any code that is converting URIs to lowercase. If those rules are in `httpd.conf` then its better to move that stuff to your .htaccess so that you can control/manage all rewrite rules from one place. Once those rules are in .htaccess you can have rule like this to avoid lowercasing certain URIs:

```
# if URI doesn't contains INDEX. then convert to lowercase
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/INDEX\.
RewriteRule ^(.*?[A-Z]+.*)$ ${lc:$1} [R,L]
```